# Multiple Multisite networks on the same domain?

Tags: multisite, installation, server, domain

This is a question I can't find the answer to:

**Can I run two separate Multisite networks under one domain?**

Here's the scenario, to better explain, we have a company website that already uses a WordPress Multisite network to run our country sites, like so:

```
http://www.companysite.com/
http://www.companysite.com/fr/
http://www.companysite.com/se/
http://www.companysite.com/de/
http://www.companysite.com/jp/
http://www.companysite.com/cn/
etc.
```

All of these sites use the same theme, the same plugins, so it makes sense to run them off one network.

Then we have a bunch of separate "stand-alone" wordpress sites that are marketing "campaign"-based sites, each one unique, usually developed by 3rd parties, with their own themes and plugins, which run of sub-directories of the multisite installations:

```
http://www.companysite.com/education
http://www.companysite.com/marketing
http://www.companysite.com/innovation
etc.
```

We don't really want to run them off the same Multisite installation because these use different themes and plugins, are written by 3rd parties, are subject to spikes due to marketing campaigns, and are less secure/stable than our country based sites network.

However, we do need them to be on the same domain...

Which brings me back to my original question:

**Can I run two separate Multisite networks under one domain?**

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Yes. Assuming these are pre-existing WP instances.  Will all WP instances be served from the same server/VM?  If so that makes it easier and you need to do some special htaccess configurations.  If they are on separate servers/VMs, then its just a bit harder - you need a proxy in front of them.

Comment: @user42826 or if they were on separate servers you could get one to mod_proxy the requests through to the other one, depending on load. But I agree htaccess is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not run different networks or different Multisite installations under one domain in the default possibilities of WP. But you can use one Multiste with multiple networks with the help of a plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/

With this plugin get you the chance to create different networks with sites in one installation, one Multisite. Like the follow structure example.

```
http://www.companysite.com/education
     -- /www.companysite.com/education/de
     -- /www.companysite.com/education/en
     -- ...
http://www.companysite.com/marketing
     -- /www.companysite.com/marketing/de
     -- /www.companysite.com/marketing/en
     -- ...
http://www.companysite.com/innovation
     -- /www.companysite.com/innovation/de
     -- /www.companysite.com/innovation/en
     -- ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install a new wordpress in a sub folder, let's call it "www2", so you'll have this URL :

```
http://www2.companysite.com/
```

Then you configure your NEW network so you can have this structure :

```
http://www2.companysite.com/education
http://www2.companysite.com/marketing
```

Now you have 2 seperate wordpress installations and 2 different networks.

Wish this is what you'r looking for :)